# Java Map: Using value object's attribute as key, bad practice?

Tags: java, dictionary

Is it bad practice to use an object's attribute as the key for a map entry? Every time I do it, it feels wrong.

For example:

```
class Foo {
  String name;
  String bar;
}
```

And then use a Map like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.name = "foo bar";
foo.bar = "blaaaa";

Map<String, Foo> foos = new HashMap<>();
foos.add(foo.name, foo);
```

It feels kind of wrong.

Comment: This is one of the most common usages of a `Map` - indexed lookup. There is no issue here. Although beware that if `Foo` is mutable then the index will become incorrect if `Foo` changes.

Comment: If your concern is memory waste, in the particular case of `String` keys, you can take advantage of the pool (see the doc of `String.intern`).

Comment: In some cases you may consider enumerations instead of classes to accomplish the same use case, but better / immutable. Then you can for instance check if something is in a `HashSet` instead of a `HashMap`, which would remove this particular concern (although I agree this is not much of an issue to be concerned about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance it feels wrong.

But using a field as **key** is reasonable, perhaps a bit redundant but legitimate.
It doesn't matter where the **key's** value comes from! Because the purpose of a `Map` is to retrieve elements. And doing it like that fairly does the job.

If you feel that guilty, you may remove the field from the class if there aren't any side-effects.

What may be wrong about that is - you're not using methods for the fields. Consider following scenerio: You'd like to combine two strings as new key. If you have referenced a field a thousand times, you are out of luck! You just have to replace all occurences of the field. This may lead to bugs and inconveniences if you accidentally replaced something else.

But if you do have a method, you just change the part in the method and you're done.

Comment: The two last paragraphs are not really clear (to me).

Comment: I always use methods, just used fields for a quick example. Thanks anyway! :)